# MNIST missing training labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I am new to deep learning and tried to make a program to recognize the handwritten digits. For this, I downloaded the MNIST dataset but I noticed there are some missing labels of the training dataset and because of this I am unable to train my model. Can anyone help me and tell me how I can solve such a problem?

Or can anyone please share with me the training model labels zip file so that I can train my model?

```
Size of training images = 60000       Size of training labels = 59992
```

ERROR:

```
number of rows in x (60000) does not match length of y (59992)
Apply node that caused the error: CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias(Dot22.0, b, targets)
Toposort index: 33
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(60000, 10), (10,), (59992,)]
Inputs strides: [(80, 8), (8,), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.0)], [CrossentropySoftmax1HotWithBiasDx(Elemwise{Inv}[(0, 0)].0, CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.1, targets)], []]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debug print and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

DATASET LINK - http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

MY CODE TO EXTRACT DATA:

```
def load_dataset():
    def download(filename,source="http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/"):
        print("Downloading",filename)
        import urllib.request
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(source+filename,filename)

    def load_mnist_image(filename):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            download(filename)

        import gzip

        with gzip.open(filename,'rb') as f:
            data=np.frombuffer(f.read(),np.uint8,offset=16)
            data=data.reshape(-1,1,28,28)

        return data/np.float32(256)

    def load_mnist_label(filename):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            download(filename)

        import gzip

        with gzip.open(filename,'rb') as f:
            data=np.frombuffer(f.read(),np.uint8,offset=16)

        return data
    x_train=load_mnist_image('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
    y_train=load_mnist_label('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
    x_test=load_mnist_image('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
    y_test=load_mnist_label('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')

    return x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test
```

Length check:

```
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=load_dataset()
print('X - '+str(len(x_train)))
print('Y - '+str(len(y_train)))
```

output:

X - 60000
Y - 59992

HERE IS MY FULL CODE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
for i in range(1,x_train.size):
    plt.show(plt.imshow(x_train[i][0]))
    print(y_train)

import theano
import lasagne as lse
import theano.tensor as T

def build_nn(input_var=None):
    l_input=lse.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None,1,28,28),input_var=input_var)
    ldrop=lse.layers.DropoutLayer(l_input,p=0.2)
    l_hid1=lse.layers.DenseLayer(ldrop,num_units=800,
                                  nonlinearity=lse.nonlinearities.rectify,
                                  W=lse.init.GlorotUniform())
    l_hid1_drop=lse.layers.DropoutLayer(l_hid1,p=0.5)

    l_hid2=lse.layers.DenseLayer(l_hid1_drop,num_units=800,
                                  nonlinearity=lse.nonlinearities.rectify,
                                  W=lse.init.GlorotUniform())
    l_hid2_drop=lse.layers.DropoutLayer(l_hid2,p=0.5)

    l_output=lse.layers.DenseLayer(l_hid2_drop,num_units=10,nonlinearity=lse.nonlinearities.softmax)

    return l_output

input_var=T.tensor4('inputs')
target_var=T.ivector('targets')

network=build_nn(input_var)
prediction=lse.layers.get_output(network)

loss=lse.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(prediction,target_var)

loss=loss.mean()

params=lse.layers.get_all_params(network,trainable=True)

update=lse.updates.nesterov_momentum(loss,params,learning_rate=1,momentum=0.9)
tain_fn=theano.function([input_var,target_var],loss,updates=update)


num_training_step=1000

for steps in range(num_training_step):
    train_err=tain_fn(x_train,y_train)
    print('Step '+str(steps))
```

FULL ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    902             outputs =\
--> 903                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    904                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)

ValueError: number of rows in x (60000) does not match length of y (59992)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-2827076f729d> in <module>
      2 
      3 for steps in range(num_training_step):
----> 4     train_err=tain_fn(x_train,y_train)
      5     print('Step '+str(steps))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    915                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    916                     thunk=thunk,
--> 917                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    918             else:
    919                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    323         # extra long error message in that case.
    324         pass
--> 325     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    326 
    327 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    690                 value = tp()
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    693             raise value
    694         finally:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    901         try:
    902             outputs =\
--> 903                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    904                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)
    905         except Exception:

ValueError: number of rows in x (60000) does not match length of y (59992)
Apply node that caused the error: CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias(Dot22.0, b, targets)
Toposort index: 33
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(60000, 10), (10,), (59992,)]
Inputs strides: [(80, 8), (8,), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.0)], [CrossentropySoftmax1HotWithBiasDx(Elemwise{Inv}[(0, 0)].0, CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.1, targets)], []]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: This is the error, what about the code that downloaded the dataset?? or even the URL??

Comment: @Anwarvic   Here is the link from where I downloaded my dataset.   Link- http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Comment: yup, that's the official URL... what about the code that you used for training

Comment: @Anwarvic please check question again! I updated and added all the essential information needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have downloaded and loaded the data manually which isn't recommended. I think you should consider downloading and loading the data using a rather stable method. According to the official documentation [here](https://keras.io/datasets/), you can use this simple method to do what you want like so:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

**NOTE**:
If you do not have the index file locally (at '~/.keras/datasets/'), it will be downloaded to this location.